# Document inserted with all fields in an embedded document called "0"

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I do `db.persons.find();` I have one document `{ "id" : "yn4toWcMXtsK7E9Ds", "0" : { "id" : "1010", "name" : "xxx", "address" : "some address" } }`

This document added in my database in server side.

My code:

```
Meteor.startup(function () { 
   if (Persons.find().count() === 0) { 
      var person = [ { '_id': "1010", 'name': "xxx", 'address':"some address" }]; 
      Persons.insert(person); 
   }
};
```

Why the field "0" added ? How can I access it ? if not, how can I change the way it's writen in the database ? 
For example, when I do `db.persons.find();` I want something like: `{ "_id" : "1010", "name" : "xxx", "address" : "some address" }`

Answer (score 2):

"0" field is added because a person variable it's an array.

You can get Your result by:

```
Meteor.startup(function () { 
  if (Persons.find().count() === 0) {
    Persons.insert({ _id : "1010", "name" : "xxx", "address" : "some address"  });
  }
)};
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is:

```
var person = {
  '_id': "1010",
  'name': "xxx",
  'address': "some address"
};
```

without `[]`!